# How can we show that all square function are absolute integrable

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

All square integrable functions are absolutely integrable. Justify if the statement is true or false.

In this statement I want to prove this statement by using Cauchy-schwarz inequality
As we know square integrable function defined as

$\int_{\infty}^{\infty} \lvert f(x) \rvert^2 dx < \infty$

and we have to show that

$\int_{\infty}^{\infty} \lvert f(x) \rvert dx < \infty$ (absolute integrable).

But when I am applying Cauchy-schwarz inequality, complex function is coming. How to proceed? Or is my methodology wrong?

Answer (score 3):

This is false; simply take $f = \frac 1x \cdot 1_{[1,\infty)}$ (if you want a continuous or smooth function, you can find some way to smooth this out). The square of this is integrable because $\int_1^\infty \frac 1{x^2} d x < \infty$ (you can use the FTC on it even), but $\int_1^\infty \frac 1x d x$ is infinite.